# facebook page referrer

Tags: php, facebook

I have set up my own Facebook page and would like to track analytics but use my own tools. Is it possible to track the referrer information?

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` will provide it in PHP. But keep in mind, for various reasons, this can be unreliable.